# How many ways there are to divide $5$-element set to at mot three sets?

Tags: combinatorics, self-learning

How many ways there are to divide $5$-element set to at most three subsets? If I am right, then I have following subsets:

1 subset: containing five elements (that is 1 possibility)

2 subsets:

- 1 element and 4 elements (that is ${5 \choose 1}\cdot {4 \choose 4}$ possibilities)
- 2 elements and 3 elements (that is ${5 \choose 2}\cdot {3 \choose 3}$ possibilities)

3 subsets:

- 1 el. 1 el. and 3 el. (that is ${5 \choose 1}\cdot {4 \choose 1}\cdot {3 \choose 3}$ possibilities)
- 2 el. 2 el. and 1 el. (that is ${5 \choose 2}\cdot {3 \choose 2}\cdot {1 \choose 1}$ possibilities)

Now I just need to sum that all up. Did I solve it correctly?

Comment: are empty subsets allowed?

Comment: @drhab The problem is that it isn't mentioned in the exercise.

Comment: @graydad As written: at most

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are problems with the three subsets analysis.

We count the number of splittings of type $1$-$1$-$3$. The objects that form the $3$-set can be chosen in $\binom{5}{3}$ ways. Now it's over!

Alternately, the $2$ objects that will be lonely can be chosen in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways. Now it's over.

Similarly, you have double-counted the splittings of type $2$-$2$-$1$.

**Remark:** Your $\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{1}$ counts the splittings $\{A\}, \{B\}, \{C,D,E\}$ and $\{B\}, \{A\}, \{C,D,E\}$ as different.

We have left the correction of the $2$-$2$-$1$ count to you. Please leave a message if there ia difficulty.

Comment: So for the 2-2-1 case it will be ${5 \choose 2}{3 \choose 2}$, right?

Comment: The answer in your comment is the same as the answer in the OP, and is not right. There are various ways to analyze. For example, there are $\binom{5}{4}$ ways to choose the $4$ people who will be split into couples. Once we have these $4$ people, they can be split into $2$ couples in $3$ ways. For take the **oldest** of our $4$ people. Her partner can be chosen in $3$ ways. That gives a total of $15$, half of your $30$. Or else we can observe that your procedure double-counts each $2$-$2$-$1$ splitting, so we can adjust by dividing your answer by $2$.

Comment: This issue comes up moderately often, for example in counting the number of "two pairs" hands in poker. Double-counting, or multiple counting, happens frequently until one gets sensitized to it.

Answer (score 1):

For two singletons and one subset of $3$ elements there are $\binom{5}{2}=10$ possibilities. So not $20$. You count the possibilities twice.

For one singleton and two subsets of $2$ elements you make a sortlike mistake.